# Access nested structure to declare variable

Tags: c

Can we access a nested data member of structure and use it to declare a variable?

```
typedef struct foo {
  struct {
    int a; 
    int b; 
  }bar;
}foo;
```

Is it possible to create a variable of type bar:

```
foo f; 
struct bar *bar = &f.bar;
```

My intention is to declare the data type `bar` so that I can avoid the long variable name `f.bar.a` and replace it with `bar->a`

Comment: Yes, but `f.bar` is invalid because `foo` doesn't have a *member variable* `bar`.

Comment: Isn't this better?
`typedef struct bar {
    int a; 
    int b; 
  }bar;`
now that bar is defined do this:

`typedef struct foo {
bar b1;
}foo;`

Comment: `typedef struct` is a C thing, you don't need it in C++.

Comment: @MikeCAT I updated the code such that the member variable bar would be present, but with this change the error is of non-static member reference.

Comment: `foo::bar` is not C.  Recommend one language and code that compiles to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you give the inner struct a tag name:

```
typedef struct foo {
  struct bar {
    int a; 
    int b; 
  }bar;
}foo;
```

Then you can use that name to declare variables of that type:

```
foo f; 
struct bar *bar = &f.bar;
```

Comment: [Compilation error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/koA6cznl3YendxuY): cannot convert 'foo::bar*' to 'main()::bar*' in initialization

Comment: @MikeCAT You're using a C++ compiler.

Comment: The language is unclear. Tag is edited not by OP. Bad question.

Comment: Hmm, I see no difference with the code in the question.

Comment: @rustyx The question doesn't have a tag on the inner struct.

Answer (score 0):

> My intention is to declare the data type bar so that I can avoid the long variable name f.bar.a and replace it with bar->a

That's two things: "data type bar" and access to `bar->a` (where *bar* is a variable, not a (necessarily) a type).

I would suggest taking advantage of anonymous structs in C11:

```
typedef struct foo {
  struct bar {
    int a; 
    int b; 
  };  // unnamed struct
} foo;
```

This defines `struct bar` in addition to `struct foo` and `foo`.  It *almost* gives you what you ask for in terms of access: because the `struct bar` member has no name, you get to `a` using `foo` as in

```
foo f;
f->a = 7;
```